# REST API design + standard MVC webapp

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications, rest, jersey

I guess this more of a design question, but I currently have a REST (Jersey) web application that exposes an API that allows for users to search info for particular URLs.

The users need to sign up/log in to receive an API generated key which they will then use when accessing our API etc. Essentially anything to do with exposing the API or accessing it via GETS, POSTS etc will be held here.

So the above serves as one web app.

However I need to design an Admin component to this site, essentially providing functionality for administrators to add new users, limit the number of requests users can send to our API, throttle users if they exceed there allotted requests etc. Now I am thinking for this component, should I just develop a separate Admin web app with a standard MVC framework (e.g. Spring MVC) and treat this separate from the REST API webapp?

In my mind it seems a little unnatural to use REST for administrative aspects of a website as REST in my eyes is solely for exposing an API as a service to clients. Or is it correct to combine this adminsitrative aspect into the existing REST webapp?

What I intend to do is as follows:

1. REST API webapp connecting to a nosql persistent store. Clients can log in to view there user information i.e. like a dashboard, and request history for API services they have used etc
2. Separate Webapp for Administration using MVC to handle all admin aspects.

Mind you both with share a Mysql store for accessing user credential information, separate from the second store that will actually hold the dataset information for URLS.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not Admin as a client API? You can easily command line script it, and you'll get the Admin server up and running quickly.

Any GUI you want can be added later utilizing the Admin API so there's no throw away code.

This is my preferred Admin route.